# Pagination in Dynamo DB Results with Completable Future

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, completable-future

I am querying Dynamo DB for a given primary key. Primary Key consists of two UUID fields (fieldUUID1, fieldUUID2).
I have a lot of queries to be executed for the above primary key combination with list of values. For which i am using Asynchronous CompleteableFuture with ExecutorService with a thread pool of size 4.

After all the queries return results, which is `CompletableFuture<Object>`, i join them using `allOf` method of completable future which ensures that all the query execution is complete, and it gives me `CompletableFuture<void>`,  on which using stream i receive `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>`

If some of the queries result in pagination of result, i.e. returns `lastEvaluatedKey`, there is no way for me to know which Query Request returned this.

if i do a .get() call while i received `CompletableFuture, this will be a blocking operation, which defeats the purpose of using asynchronous. Is there a way i can handle this scenario?

example:

I can try thenCompose method, but how do i know at what point i need to stop when lastEvaluatedKey is absent.

```
for (final QueryRequest queryRequest : queryRequests) {
    final CompletableFuture<QueryResult> futureResult =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
            dynamoDBClient.query(queryRequest), executorService));

    if (futureResult == null) {
        continue;
    }

    futures.add(futureResult);
}

// Wait for completion of all of the Futures provided
final CompletableFuture<Void> allfuture = CompletableFuture
    .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));

// The return type of the CompletableFuture.allOf() is a
// CompletableFuture<Void>. The limitation of this method is that it does not
// return the combined results of all Futures. Instead we have to manually get
// results from Futures. CompletableFuture.join() method and Java 8 Streams API
// makes it simple:
final CompletableFuture<List<QueryResult>> allFutureList = allfuture.thenApply(val -> {
    return futures.stream().map(f -> f.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
});


final List<QueryOutcome> completableResults = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    try {
        // at this point all the Futures should be done, because we already executed
        // CompletableFuture.allOf method.
        final List<QueryResult> returnedResult = allFutureList.get();
        for (final QueryResult queryResult : returnedResult) {
            if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey()) {
                // how to get hold of original request  and include last evaluated key ?
            }
        }
    } finally {

    }
} finally {

}
```

I can rely on .get() method, but it will be a blocking call.

Comment: Why is it a problem to use a blocking call? All the previous fetching operations are already performed asynchronously in parallel, right? What should your thread be doing instead? As a side note, you don't need to check `futureResult == null`, `supplyAsync()` will never return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

Yes, checking (futureResult == null) is completely avoidable, Thanks for the suggestion, Didier.

Don't you think if the future hasn't returned the result yet, another queries which have returned result can utilise this thread rather than waiting for .get() to complete?

Because there are 1000+ queries running, and with a executor pool of 4 would be contagious, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

the quick solution to your need is to change your `futures` list. Instead of having it store `CompletableFuture<QueryResult>` you can change to store `CompletableFuture<RequestAndResult>` where `RequestAndResult` is a simple data class holding a `QueryRequest` and a `QueryResult`. To do that you need to change your first loop.

Then, once the `allfuture` completes you can iterate over `futures` and get access to both the requests and the results.

However, there is a deeper issue here. What are you planning to do once you have access to the origianl `QueryRequest`? my guess is that you want to issue a followup request with `exclusiveStartKey` set to whatever the response's `lastEvaluatedKey` holds. This means that you will wait for all original queries to complete and only then you'll issue the next bunch. This is inefficient: if a query returned with a `lastEvaluatedKey` you want to issue its followup query ASAP.

To achieve this my advise to you is to introduce a new method which takes a single `QueryRequest` object and returns a `CompletableFuture<QueryResult>`. Its implementation will be roughly as follows:

- issue a query with the given request
- once the result arrives check it. if its `lastEvaluatedKey` is empty return it as the result of the method
- otherwise, update request.exclusiveStartKey and go back to the first step.

Yes, its a bit harder to do that with `CompletableFutures` (compared to blocking code) but is totally doable.

Once you have that method your code needs to call this method once for each of the requests in `queryRequests`, put the returned `CompletableFuture`s in a list,  and do a `CompletableFuture.allOf()` on that list. Once the allOf future completes you can just use the results - no need to do issue followup queries.

Comment: When we check if result arrived with lastEvaluatedKey, we're already invoking .get() of the CompletableFuture, which is already a blocking call.

I was imagining it to be - Once all the CompletableFutures have returned the result, all the .get() are done, and I can check them individually if some of them have paginated result sent by checking lastEvaluatedKey.

But then as you said, if we check that after all the evaluation is done, this is inefficient and we shall issue the follow up query ASAP. That would defeat the purpose of CompletableFuture.